# If equivalent without using conditional operations and other loop methods java

Tags: java

```
int function(int a, int b, int c){
        if(a==c)
            return a;
        else 
            return b;
    }
```

Question is to achieve a same o/p without using if, while, do, for, switch,conditional expression(?:) and other general inbuilt methods like equals

Please tell me the logic and code..

Comment: This is equivalent form of if. So this answer is not accepted. You should not use this ternary operator concept

Comment: This question isn't useful, at least without more context. Why do you want to do something that is effectively conditional behaviour, without using conditionals?

Comment: this was an interview question.

Comment: `return ((a - c) && b) || a;`

Comment: @JordanTrudgett - compilation error.  `||` and `&&` do not apply to `int`.

Comment: @JordanTrudgett, yeah, you may be on the right track, but Java booleans don't work like that.

Comment: Indeed.. I was using Python :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using operators only:

```
int function(int a, int b, int c) {
    //If a == c: result = 0x00000000
    //Else:      result = 0xFFFFFFFF
    int result = (a - c | c - a) >> 31;

    //If a == c: result = 0x00000000 & (a ^ b) = 0
    //Else:      result = 0xFFFFFFFF & (a ^ b) = a ^ b
    result &= a ^ b;

    //If a == c: result = 0       ^ a = a
    //Else:      result = (a ^ b) ^ a = b
    result ^= a;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one fairly straightforward option:

```
int function(int a, int b, int c) {
    java.util.HashMap<Boolean, Integer> map = new java.util.HashMap<Boolean, Integer>();

    map.put(true, a);
    map.put(false, b);

    return map.get(a == c);
}
```

Using maps to emulate switch statements in languages that don't have them is pretty common. Using them to emulate if statements is probably an abuse.

Answer (score 3):

I really wish I came up with Cairnarvon's solution. Here's what I got, but in any case you'll end up using conditional statements somewhere hidden in a function call, unless you can figure out how to do this with bitwise operators.

```
public static int fn(int a, int b, int c) {
    Boolean equal = (a == c);

    //if equal is false, compareTo will return 0.
    //if equal is true, compareTo will return any positive integer, thus we take mod 2 to ensure this is 1
    int ret_a = equal.compareTo(Boolean.FALSE) % 2;

    //if ret_a is 0, make ret_b = 1
    //if ret_a is 1, make ret_b = 0
    int ret_b = (ret_a + 1) % 2;

    //one of these two terms is guaranteed to be zero, therefore you will only
    //return the value of a, or b.
    return (ret_a * a) + (ret_b * b);
}
```

Here is my attempt at a solution with no comparison or bit twiddling. Sadly as @Pshemo pointed out my logic is flawed.

```
    public static int fn(int a, int b, int c) {

    //I assumed this will return 1 if not a != c
            //See Pshemo's comment about why this is wrong.
    int not_equal = ((a - c) * (a - c) ) % 2;

    int ret_a = (not_equal + 1) % 2;
    int ret_b = not_equal;

    //one of these two terms is guaranteed to be zero, therefore you will only
    //return the value of a, or b.
    return (ret_a * a) + (ret_b * b);
}
```

Comment: In second solution assumption that `((a - c) * (a - c) ) % 2` will return 1 for `a != c` will be false if both a and c will be odd (1,3) or even (2,4).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possible approaches, including:

1. Do the test in native code.  That's cheating.
2. Find some library class that can used to do the job. There are probably lots of variations on this approach; e.g. see @Cairnarvon's answer.
3. Do something tricky to generate an exception (or not) depending on the inputs.  My initial idea was to use division by zero, but here's another way ...

   ```
   int insanelyStupidConditional (int a, int b, int c) {
       int[] dummy = new int[1];

       try {
           int foo = dummy[a - c];
       } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
           return b;
       }
       return a;
   }
   ```
4. Bit twiddling ... like @Vlad's answer

---

Anyway, the point of the interview question is not the answer, but whether you are *able* to think outside of the box to arrive at something.  The *most practical* answer is "change the requirements ... this is insane".

Answer (score 1):

Another way

Base idea `return b * f(a,c) + a * (1 - f(a,c))` where

- `f(a,c) -> 1` for `a != c`
- `f(a,c) -> 0` for `a == c`

so

- for `a!=c` we will return `b*(1) + a*(0);`
- and for `a==c` we will return `b*(0) + a*(1);`

code

```
public static int test(int a, int b, int c) {
    // (a - c) | (c - a) will give 
    // for a != b negative value
    // for a == c zero

    // to get sign of that value we need to get highest bit
    // so >>>31 will do the trick

    int signum = ((a - c) | (c - a)) >>> 31;
    //for a == c -> signum = 0 
    //for a != c -> signum = 1 (it indicates that (a - c) | (c - a) was negative) 

    return b * signum + a * (1 - signum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go, no `if`, `while`, `do`, `for`, `switch`, inline if `(?:)`, or any other operator (`==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, etc.):

```
int function(int a, int b, int c){
    int[] result = {-1, a, b};
    return result[new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a, c)).size()];
}
```

**Logic:** Adds both `a` and `c` to a `Set`. If they are equal, they'll be added only once, and the set's size will be `1`. If they are different, the size will be `2`.